# Creating a pseudo terminal in C++ that can be used by other programs

Tags: c++, linux, pty

I have created a pseudo terminal in C++ using the following code:

```
int main(int, char const *[])
{
  int master, slave;
  char name[1024];
  char mode[] = "0777"; //I know this isn't good, it is for testing at the moment
  int access;

  int e = openpty(&master, &slave, &name[0], 0, 0);
  if(0 > e) {
    std::printf("Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return -1;
  }

  if( 0 != unlockpt(slave) )
  {
      perror("Slave Error");
  }

  access = strtol(mode, 0, 8);

  if( 0 > chmod(name, access) )
  {
      perror("Permission Error");
  }

  //std::cout << "Master: " << master << std::endl;
  std::printf("Slave PTY: %s\n", name);

  int r;
  prompt = "login: ";

  while(true) 
  {
    std::cout << prompt << std::flush;
    r = read(master, &name[0], sizeof(name)-1);
    checkInput(name);
    name[r] = '\0';
    std::printf("%s", &name[0]);
    std::printf("\n");
  }

  close(slave);
  close(master);

  return 0;
}
```

It works pretty well in the sense that from another terminal, I can do:

> printf 'username' > /dev/pts/x

and it will appear and be processed as it should.

My question is: when I try to use screen, nothing appears on the screen terminal. Then when I type,  it comes through to my slave 1 character at a time.

Does anyone know why this is? Or how I can fix it.

I can provide more detail if required.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're not flushing the buffer after you use `printf`.

Comment: Does this mean I need to tell the slave to wait for me to flush before it does any processing?

Answer (score 0):

As pauls answer already suggest you need to flush the buffer.

To do so you can use the tcflush function.

The first argument is the int of the file descriptor and the second can be one of the following:

- TCIFLUSH Flushes input data that has been received by the system but
  not read by an application.
- TCOFLUSH Flushes output data that has been written by an application
  but not sent to the terminal.
- TCIOFLUSH Flushes both input and output data.

For more information see: **https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.3.0?topic=functions-tcflush-flush-input-output-terminal**